# Variable font height via tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex, typesetting

I've been looking for a more elegant solution to the following typesetting problem. Consider those banners found in print media where the text is aligned like:

```
B    I    G        T   E   X   T
small text small text small text
m o r e    m e d i u m   t e x t
```

The font sizes are adjusted so that the height is scaled down for longer lines of text such that each line has equal width. I've written a small script that runs each line separately, compiles, crops the resulting pdf and then `\includegraphics` each in a table. This gives the desired effect but requires an both an outside script and pdfcrop (which only crops to a white bounding box). Since much of LaTeX is self-aware, I imagine it would be possible to have it recognize the width of a box and scale it appropriately so that any text fits exactly into the desired width.

Any thoughts or ideas on how a pure LaTeX implementation might work?

**EDIT** As a supplement to the suggested solution by AVB (since large code in comments looks awful), I've posted below the code used so that others may find it easily.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[l]
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{BIG Text} \\
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{small text small text small text} \\ 
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{Medium Text Medium Text}
\end{table} \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read the TeX FAQ entry titled [Changing the space between letters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-letterspace). Depending on your circumstances, the packages and recommendation in that FAQ may suffice.

Also, take a look at the `\scalebox` and `\resizebox` commands in the [`graphicx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package. They do what the names imply.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that this could be improved upon, and due to different font implementations at different sizes then it isn't going to be exact, but here's a quick-and-dirty way to do it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}


\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\testwidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{4in}
\newcommand{\fixedwidth}[1]{%
\settowidth{\testwidth}{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{round(\mywidth/\testwidth * 10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{round(\mywidth/\testwidth * 15)}%
\bgroup\fontsize{\x pt}{\y pt}\selectfont#1\egroup}

\begin{document}

\fixedwidth{hello world}

\fixedwidth{greetings earthlings}
\end{document}
```

In practice, it's a little less than the 4in, but the two lines of text do get scaled to the same amount.

Comment: Interesting solution Andrew - it seems that in practice, using the round does not get them to line up _exactly_, but instead very close.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure whether fonts could be non-integer sizes.  I guess that they can, so the "round" may be superfluous.  Anyway, you got a better answer so it's not important.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the package [textfit](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/textfit/). Usage:

```
\scaletowidth{width}{text}
```

or

```
\scaletoheight{height}{text}
```

Comment: Of the three examples currently posted (Geoff, Stacey, AVB) this one does the worst at aligning the right-side column exactly. While it looks nice for a larger block of text, for the short headlines I'm looking for its a bit to jagged on the right-side. (+1) For introducing me to the package - its seems useful in its own regard!